# Why does django print the traceback of an exception even though I catch it?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a django web app and am currently in the process of writing tests for it.

I want to check that my URL paths are working. In order messages that clutter the screen when testing, I tried catching the exceptions that get thrown, but this doesn't seem to work.

Here's my method where I'm testing the path of the home URL:

```
    def test_home(self):

    path = '/'

    try:
        response = self.client.get(path)
    except Exception:
        assert False, ("There seems to be a problem with the view corresponding to the path", path)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, ("Couldn't load page with page", path))
```

And this is the output:

```
<a lot more exceptions>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 395: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/project/project/app/tests/test_urls.py", line 16, in test_home
    response = self.client.get(path)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 395: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/project/project/app/tests/test_urls.py", line 18, in test_home
    assert False, ("There seems to be a problem with the view corresponding to the path", path)
AssertionError: ('There seems to be a problem with the view corresponding to the path', '/')
```

My main problem is that I get this huge error message, that, as as far as I understand, should not be shown when the exception is caught. On top of that, it seems to me that the last line of the method is executed, which I don't want to happen either. My last issue is that in the error log, it says 'path'. Path is a variable, so why isn't its value used?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The exception is not thrown by `self.client.get`. So it never "leaves" that level. It is handled internally, and you will receive a HTTP response that shows something is not right.

Comment: You are trying to handle that error but causing a new error yourself. What do you expect `assert False, "error message"` to do?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that makes sense. Is there a way to prevent these exceptions from being thrown/ suppress them?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm not sure if I really understand what you mean, but I want the try block to catch any exeptions and if an exception is thrown, I want to let the test fail.

Comment: @YeuhYeuh You can see the line `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:` meaning your try-except caught the exception **but** then you run `assert False, ...` immediately throwing a new error. So it along with the exceptions it tried to handle all are shown. Instead set a flag variable to `False` (initialized to `True` at the start) inside the except and write the assert after the `try-except` using this flag variable